# Script Mediator Javascript does not work properly on WSO2 EI ESB

Tags: javascript, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Good afternoon, I am new to the WSO2 ESB and I am working with an api in which we are using a mediator script with javascript, however I get that the script does not work correctly, basically the script which takes the value and makes it some transformation, however, at the log level I see that the variable only indicates a value of True, as if it were boolean

My API is the following:

```
 <filter xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" regex="200">
    <then>
       <property xmlns:ns3="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1" name="balance" expression="$body/ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse/ns3:balance/text()"/>
       <property xmlns:ns3="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1" name="negativeBalance" expression="$body/ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse/ns3:negativeBalance/text()"/>
       <property xmlns:ns3="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1" name="exponentBalance" expression="$body/ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse/ns3:balance/@exponent"/>
       <property xmlns:ns3="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1" name="exponentNegativeBalance" expression="$body/ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse/ns3:negativeBalance/@exponent"/>
       <property name="balanceLength" expression="fn:string-length(get-property('balance'))"/>
       <property name="negativeBalanceLength" expression="fn:string-length(get-property('negativeBalance'))"/>
       <script language="js">var exponent = mc.getProperty('exponentBalance');                  var balance = mc.getProperty('balance');                  if(exponent > 0) {         var itera = exponent * -1;                    var zero = '0';          for (i = 0; i &lt; itera; ++i) {           zero = zero.concat('0');    }             var result = balance.concat(zero);                   }   mc.setProperty("RESULT", String(result));</script>
       <filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('exponentBalance')) > 0">
          <then>
             <property name="beforeBalance" expression="fn:concat($ctx:balance,'0000000000000000000')"/>
             <property name="balanceResponse" expression="fn:substring($ctx:beforeBalance,1,$ctx:balanceLength+$ctx:exponentBalance)"/>
          </then>
          <else>
             <filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('exponentBalance')) = 0">
                <then>
                   <property name="balanceResponse" expression="$ctx:balance"/>
                </then>
                <else>
                   <filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('balance')) = 0">
                      <then>
                         <property name="beforeBalance" expression="fn:substring($ctx:balance,1,$ctx:balanceLength+$ctx:exponentBalance)"/>
                         <property name="stringToInsertbalance" value="."/>
                         <property name="afterBalance" expression="fn:substring($ctx:balance,$ctx:balanceLength+$ctx:exponentBalance+1)"/>
                         <property name="balanceResponse" expression="fn:concat(0,$ctx:beforeBalance,$ctx:stringToInsertbalance,$ctx:afterBalance)"/>
                      </then>
                      <else>
                         <property name="beforeBalance" expression="fn:substring($ctx:balance,1,$ctx:balanceLength+$ctx:exponentBalance)"/>
                         <property name="stringToInsertbalance" value="."/>
                         <property name="afterBalance" expression="fn:substring($ctx:balance,$ctx:balanceLength+$ctx:exponentBalance+1)"/>
                         <property name="balanceResponse" expression="fn:concat($ctx:beforeBalance,$ctx:stringToInsertbalance,$ctx:afterBalance)"/>
                      </else>
                   </filter>
                </else>
             </filter>
          </else>
       </filter>
       <log>
          <property name="balance" expression="$ctx:balance"/>
          <property name="balanceLength" expression="$ctx:balanceLength"/>
          <property name="negativeBalanceLength" expression="$ctx:negativeBalanceLength"/>
          <property name="exponentBalance" expression="$ctx:exponentBalance"/>
          <property name="exponentNegativeBalance" expression="$ctx:exponentNegativeBalance"/>
          <property name="beforeBalance" expression="$ctx:beforeBalance"/>
          <property name="beforeNegativeBalance" expression="$ctx:beforeNegativeBalance"/>
          <property name="stringToInsertbalance" expression="$ctx:stringToInsertbalance"/>
          <property name="stringToInsertNegativeBalance" expression="$ctx:stringToInsertNegativeBalance"/>
          <property name="afterBalance" expression="$ctx:afterBalance"/>
          <property name="afterBalanceNegative" expression="$ctx:afterBalanceNegative"/>
          <property name="balanceResponse" expression="$ctx:balanceResponse"/>
          <property name="negativeBalanceResponse" expression="$ctx:negativeBalanceResponse"/>
          <property name="result" expression="get-property('result')"/>
          <property name="absolute" expression="get-property('absolute')"/>
       </log>
```

The script that I am using at the javascript level is the following:

```
<script language="js">var exponent = mc.getProperty('exponentBalance');                  var balance = mc.getProperty('balance');                  if(exponent > 0) {             var itera = exponent * -1;                    var zero = '0';               for (i = 0; i &lt; itera; ++i) {           zero = zero.concat('0');                        }             var result = balance.concat(zero);                   }                  mc.setProperty("RESULT", String(result));</script>
```

[image]

The same if I add a fixed value to the Result variable, it always shows True, I am using the WSO2 EI 6.5

What could be happening?

**UPDATE**

Update the line to set the variable as defined below:

```
<script language="js">var exponent = mc.getProperty('exponentBalance');                  var balance = mc.getProperty('balance');                  if(exponent > 0) {             var itera = exponent * -1;                    var zero = '0';               for (i = 0; i &lt; itera; ++i) {           zero = zero.concat('0');                        }             var result = balance.concat(zero);                   }                  mc.setProperty("result", String(result));</script>
```

Where the following line was modified:

```
mc.setProperty("result", String(result))
```

However, I get the following at the log level:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you have set the value "true" for the property "result". This is because you are not setting any value for the property "result" in the script mediator.

In the script mediator you are setting the value with the property name "RESULT" whereas you are obtaining the value of the property with the property name "result".

```
mc.setProperty("RESULT", String(result));
<property name="result" expression="get-property('result')"/>
```

If you want to access the value set within the script mediator, you need to set the value as following.

```
mc.setProperty("result", String(result));
```

**Update based on the first comment**

The reason for this behaviour is that, you have defined the variable "**result**" within the if condition of the script mediator. In case the if condition is not executed, the "**result**" will be undefined. You need to define the var "result" before the if condition with a default value.

Comment: Thanks.Modify my question according to what you indicate and I get an error of type undefined in the logs

Comment: How I do this ?. Can you give me an example please